# How to properly plot ICE in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, ice

I want to plot Individual Conditional Expectation (ICE), and I have the following code segment:

```
library(caret)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(ggridges)
library(ggthemes)
library(iml)
library(partykit)
library(rpart)
library(tidyverse)

theme_set(theme_minimal())
set.seed(88)

kfolds <- 3

load_dataset <- function() {
  dataset <- read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dmpe/bfe07a29c7fc1e3a70d0522956d8e4a9/raw/7ea71f7432302bb78e58348fede926142ade6992/pima-indians-diabetes.csv", col_names=FALSE)  %>%
    mutate(X9=as.factor(ifelse(X9== 1, "diabetes", "nondiabetes")))
  X = dataset[, 1:8]
  Y = dataset$X9
  return(list(dataset, X, Y))
}

compute_rf_model <- function(dataset) {
  index <- createDataPartition(dataset$X9,
                               p=0.8,
                               list=FALSE,
                               time=1)

  dataset_train <- dataset[index,]
  dataset_test <- dataset[-index,]

  fit_control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",
                              number=kfolds,
                              repeats=1,
                              classProbs=TRUE,
                              savePredictions=TRUE,
                              verboseIter=FALSE,
                              allowParallel=FALSE,
                              summaryFunction=defaultSummary)

  rf_model <- train(X9~.,
                    data=dataset_train,
                    method="rf",
                    preProcess=c("center","scale"),
                    trControl=fit_control,
                    metric="Accuracy",
                    verbose=FALSE)
  return(list(rf_model, dataset_train, dataset_test))
}


main <- function() {
  data <- load_dataset()
  dataset <- data[[1]]
  X <- data[[2]]
  Y <- data[[3]]

  rf_model_data <- compute_rf_model(dataset)
  rf_model <- rf_model_data[[1]]
  dataset_train <- rf_model_data[[2]]
  dataset_test <- rf_model_data[[3]]

  X <- dataset_train    %>%
    select(-X9) %>%
    as.data.frame()

  predictor <- Predictor$new(rf_model, data=X, y=dataset_train$X9)

  ice <- FeatureEffect$new(predictor, feature="X2", center.at=min(X$X2), method="pdp+ice")
  ice_plot_glucose <- ice$plot() + 
    scale_color_discrete(guide="none") +
    scale_y_continuous("Predicted Diabetes")
  ice <- FeatureEffect$new(predictor, feature="X4", center.at=min(X$X4), method="pdp+ice")
  ice_plot_insulin <- ice$plot() + 
    scale_color_discrete(guide="none") +
    scale_y_continuous("Predicted Diabetes")
  grid.arrange(ice_plot_glucose, ice_plot_insulin, ncol=1)

}

if (!interactive()) {
  main()
} else if (identical(environment(), globalenv())) {
  quit(status = main())
}
```

The plot that I receive at the end looks like this:

[image]

And this plot does not look nearly as nice some ICE plots online, such as this one below:

[image]

Any ideas why is this happening? I believe the data that I have is similar to the one shown in above post, at least value-wise.

Comment: Please consider reducing the elements in your question that are not absolutely necessary to reproduce the error / undesired behavior. What have you tried to address the problem?

Comment: @PavoDive I tried to provide here minimal reproducible problem. I don't know why the plot appears in that way.

Comment: I got the first plot, but then my RStudio session aborted. (I'm running R 3.5.2, so maybe this depends on a current version?) It does appear that the behavior is bveing triggered by this section of code: `else if (identical(environment(), globalenv())) {    quit(status = main())`

Comment: @42- Which plot do you mean by first? The one with weird lines? That’s what I receive in RStudio when I run the code, I use R 3.6.0.  But results should somehow look like the last picture, which has a lot of black lines.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I meant the one with the wierd lines.  I misinterpreted the interaction with the console. There was not a crash, but rather the behavior with the quit() function resembled a crash dialog. I wondered if that is a dataset that is publicly available (other than your gist) and is documented? I think this would be a very useful set of code for which the answer is short and sweet and the results even more interesting if they had an interpretation. Perhaps from here: https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database ?

Comment: @42- Yes, it is publicly available open source dataset. It’s the one you linked.

Comment: After reading the TOS, I'm now worried that the Kaggle database is not supposed to have copies made available without permission. Perhaps you should just leave the link to the Kaggle page in and remove the link to your copy? I think that restriction is perhaps even more important since the information is of a medical nature.

Comment: @42- I actually got the dataset from Kaggle, but it is available in many places, I just didn’t find way to link directly the .csv file from Kaggle, and wanted to give a reproducible code, hence found this link and used that. I’m not home now, I can change it later, or you can edit for me. But as I said I have seen this dataset in many places actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the predictor gives the class labels instead of the class probabilities.

Changing

`predictor <- Predictor$new(rf_model, data=X, y=dataset_train$X9)`

to

`predictor <- Predictor$new(rf_model, data=X, y=dataset_train$X9, type = "prob")`

should fix your plots.

See [these fixed PD plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx0vO.jpg)